# Calling a method inside another method of a class made with the class construct returns a Type Error (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, oop

I'm trying to make a simple game (move a block for now) on my own.
One of my class functions, that updates the game context has a method, `update()`, that calls on to other methods of the same class, `displBackground()` and `displCharacters()`.
When I see the console on my browser, I see the following message:
TypeError: this.displBackground is not a function

I've seen through:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Not_a_function
[Not able to call method within another method of the same class JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47456235/not-able-to-call-method-within-another-method-of-the-same-class-js)
(And some others, including quite some SO questions, I'm running out of time, so I will list them later)
I've not tried declaring the object directly instead of from a class, but I will save that for last resort.

```
const gameContext = class {
constructor() {
    this.c = document.getElementById("game");
    this.ctx = this.c.getContext("2d");
    this.characters = [];
    this.interval = setInterval(this.update, 20);
};
addCharacter(char) {
    this.characters.push(char)
}
displBackground() {
    this.ctx.fillStyle = '#eeeeff';
    this.ctx.fillRect(0, 0, this.c.width, this.c.height);
}
displCharacters() {
    if (this.characters == 0) return
    for (var i = 0; i < this.characters.length; i++) {
        var character = this.characters[i];
        this.ctx.fillStyle = character.color;
        this.ctx.fillRect((character.pos[0]-character.size),
                          (character.pos[1]-character.size),
                          (character.pos[0]+character.size),
                          (character.pos[1]+character.size));
    }
}
update() {
    this.displBackground();
    this.displCharacters();
    console.log(KEYMAP); // This is a function that tells me what keys are currently pressed, and works well isolated.
}
}
```

I would like to see the canvas updating 50 times a second as time goes, and later on make sure that the block can move (displBackground draws the background while dsplCharacters draws the characters, on top)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bind the methods in your constructor and you are good to go.

```
constructor() {
    this.c = document.getElementById("game");
    this.ctx = this.c.getContext("2d");
    this.characters = [];
    this.interval = setInterval(this.update, 20);


    this.update = this.update.bind(this);
    this.displBackground = this.displBackground.bind(this);
    this.displCharacters = this.displCharacters.bind(this);
};
```

what is happening is that

```
this.interval = setInterval(this.update, 20);
```

is not binding `this` to the `this.update` function.

another way to solve it is:

```
constructor() {
    this.c = document.getElementById("game");
    this.ctx = this.c.getContext("2d");
    this.characters = [];
    this.interval = setInterval( ()=> this.update(), 20);

};
```

Comment: Should be `() => this.update()` (calling parenthesis) or `this.update.bind(this)`.

Comment: totally correct @FelixKling

Comment: On the first possible answer, the interval should be set last.